# Wix prorperies value don't value is not changed after radioButton section

Tags: wix

I want to select in the office version, the default is 32 bits. But when being installed and checked the properties to copy files, select the default value, without considering my choice. How to fix it?

Product.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
 xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" 
 >
<Product Id="{95B5E9E1-AB21-4947-A047-74C169B1D1F2}" Name="Xproduct" Language="1033"   Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="X Limited" UpgradeCode="af9969f2-fb9c-44c7-b207-e89f1d900a91">
<Package InstallerVersion="301" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated" InstallScope="perMachine" AdminImage="yes" Manufacturer="X Limited" />
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
<MediaTemplate />


<Property Id="officeVersion" Value="32"/>
<UI Id="MyWebUI">
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

  <DialogRef Id="CheckVersion"/>

  <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next"
       Event="NewDialog" Value="CheckVersion"
       Order="3">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>
</UI>    

  <Feature Id="CommonFuture" Title="xInstaller" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ShotcutComponents"/>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="xComponents"/>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="PocketSoapComponent"/>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="SystemComponentsWinX86" />
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="SystemComponentsWinX64"/>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="SystemComponentsWinX64Office64"/>
  </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
  <Condition Message="You need to be an administrator to install this product.">
    Privileged
  </Condition>  
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='MyProcess.TaskKill' Before='InstallValidate'>NOT Installed</Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>

  <Property Id="System32WindowsFolder" Value="C:\Windows\System32"/>
  <Property Id="QtExecCmdLine" Value='"[WindowsFolder]\System32\taskkill.exe" /F /IM EXCEL.EXE'/>
  <CustomAction Id="MyProcess.TaskKill" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore"></CustomAction>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">      
  <Directory Id="SystemFolder" />
  <Directory Id="System32WindowsFolder"/>      


  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">        
     <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="xAddin"/>
  </Directory>

  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">          
      <Directory Id="xShorcutsDir" Name="xAddin"/>
  </Directory>  

  <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="Microsoft" Name="Microsoft">
      <Directory Id="AddIns" Name="AddIns"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>

</Directory>
</Fragment> 

<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="SystemComponentsWinX64" Directory="SystemFolder">
    <Component Id="SystemDLL" Guid="{5CC58B1B-CF05-412B-A9DC-89C4D9DDA8E3}" >
        <File Id="FILE_xXIDLL" Source="dll/system/xXlFunctions.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <Condition>officeVersion = 32 AND %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE="AMD64"</Condition>
      </Component>  
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="SystemComponentsWinX86" Directory="SystemFolder">
    <Component Id="SystemDLLx86" Guid="{8F3B689F-EC06-43C9-AF87-47DB8534EC9D}" >
      <File Id="FILE_xXIDLLx86" Source="dll/system/xXlFunctions.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      <Condition>officeVersion = 32 AND %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE="x86"</Condition>
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="SystemComponentsWinX64Office64" Directory="System32WindowsFolder">
    <Component Id="SystemDLLx64" Guid="{569E68EB-9C6D-4B72-A811-429A6901B05A}" >
      <File Id="FILE_xXIDLLx64" Source="dll/system/x64/xXlFunctions.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      <Condition>officeVersion = 64 AND %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE="AMD64"</Condition>
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="xComponents" Directory="AddIns">
    <Component Id="xXLA" Guid="{BBDA689A-B48D-4B61-8A9F-50CB0B4BC9AA}" >

      <File Id="FILE_xXLA" Source="xla/x.xla"/>        
      <RegistryValue Id="RegKeyxAddin" Root="HKCU"
                   Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\aqillaaddin"
                   Name="xAddin"
                   Value="x Excel Add-In"
                   Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
      <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveAddInsFolder" On="uninstall" Directory="AddIns"/>
    </Component>  
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ShotcutComponents" Directory="xShorcutsDir">
    <Component Id="UninstallShorcut" Guid="{BEECAC18-779F-4F6A-8D0B-2545626FD80A}">
      <Shortcut Id="UninstallShorcut"
              Name="Uninstall x Addin"
              Description="Uninstall x Addin and all of its components"
              Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
              Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" />
      <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveMyApplication" On="uninstall"/>
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
                   Key="Software\Microsoft\xAddin"
                   Name="installed"
                   Type="integer"
                   Value="1"
                   KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>  

</Wix>
```

ChecKVersion.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="CheckVersion" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName]" NoMinimize="yes" >
        <!-- Virtual Dir prompt -->
        <Control Id="Office32" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="officeVersion" Height="100" Width="200" X="50" Y="50">
          <RadioButtonGroup Property="officeVersion">
            <RadioButton Value="32" Text="Microsot Office Version 32bit" Height="17" Width="200" X="0" Y="0"/>
            <RadioButton Value="64" Text="Microsot Office Version 64bit" Height="17" Width="200" X="0" Y="20"/>
          </RadioButtonGroup>
        </Control>
        <!-- Back button -->
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243"
                Width="56" Height="17" Text="&amp;Back">
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243"
           Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="&amp;Install" ElevationShield="yes">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="1">1</Publish>

        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243"
                   Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
          <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0"
             Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="WixUI_Bmp_Banner" />
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23"
               Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
          <Text>Please select Microsoft Office Version</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234"
              Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6"
                Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
          <Text>{\WixUI_Font_Title}Microsoft Office select version</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

And another problem when the system is 64 bit I can not copy the file to C:\Windows\System32. The system automatically overrides the folder in C: \ WINDOWS \ SysWOW64 \

Answer (score 0):

Transformed into public property and it was considered

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute “Secure” to denote that the Property can be passed to the server side when doing a managed installation with elevated privileges.

```
<Property Id="OFFICEVERSION" Secure="yes" Value="32"/>
```